# Layout on Commerce checkout pages

Tags: commerce

Drupal Commerce.

On admin/commerce/config/checkout/form you can move around checkout panes between pages. This is cool!

It allows e.g. to move all panes on one page.

Now what I am trying to figure out is how to make a more interesting layout for this page. E.g. by "grouping" the panes into layout regions / columns, like I would for a node display.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get at that with the commerce functions hook_commerce_checkout_page_info() and hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info(); with more documentation on that here: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/checkout-info-hooks#checkout-pane.

It's a little complicated because the panes, pages, and forms are hard-coded into DC's checkout logic. There are a couple of modules that let you override and specify your own pages or other cart functions https://drupal.org/project/dc_co_pages, and https://drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_view_override

You'll probably need to do any serious changing by coding your own module calling the commerce functions/pages you need for your use case.

Comment: dude it's "your", not "you're" :)

Comment: i found a solution for this after i posted, and almost forgot about this issue then. Not necessarily something that is worth sharing, though. I created a module that provides a new pseudo-pane that can be placed as a separator between groups of panes. Then the display logic will pick this up and wrap the stuff in columns.

Comment: @nizzOk: I can't really spend time to verify your solution atm, since this is now done for me. But thanks nevertheless!

Comment: Thanks, Don, I'll let you know if I see any windmills :)  I'd be interested in your solution, since this is something I'll still fooling around with this stuff.

Comment: if you are interested in the columns solution i could share it somewhere. not really on drupal.org, but github maybe.

Comment: absolutely interested.

Comment: https://github.com/donquixote/drupal-commerce_checkout_columns I renamed the module to something more generic, I hope that doesn't break it. Also, only ever tried this on one site.

Comment: the code will be instructive regardless.

Comment: @donquixote : I think you should transform your prior comments in this answer to an actual answer (and mark it as accepted). If you do, please let me know about it (+1 upfront ...)